# elastic search distinct query using aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have an index with a document called Activity.

Many users create Activities. Activities have a location field. Many activities can have the same location.

When I'm presenting locations, I need to de-dup them, but I also need to allow for pagination.

1. Facets are deprecated so I've been looking at aggregations.
2. Bucket aggregation seems like it would some-what do what I want,
   although I may have to re-query with projection for any other data
   on the document.
3. It also seems like the aggregation would be applied after the query,
   which if it is paginated, then the de-duping would only happen at
   the "page" level.

Is there a way to query for unique/distinct locations and paginate the results?

Comment: I can't find a concrete question here.

Comment: I just reiterated the question from line 3, on the last line.

Comment: Can you present your query? That might make it easier for people to suggest alternatives.